# Pmt Function in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

what would be equivalent of this line that is VB.net in C#.

```
  Payment = FormatNumber(-Pmt(lRate / 1200, lTerm, lStartLoanBalance), 2)
```

Comment: Duplicate, see following post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3148882/3424480

Comment: Hows this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352165/pmt-function-payment-type

Comment: I saw this page, I dont wish to use Microsoft.VisualBasic; Also the example without using this is not giving correct answer.